# C# Serialize object into xml without formatting

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, xml-serialization

I need to serialize a c# object into xml, i could do it as in formatted section, but can we achieve it without formatting that has no indentation/extra spaces/new lines. This is required as we need to write the whole object into a csv, so we need a minified version. I tried couple of XmlWriterSettings, but it did not work as expected. Any code snippet will be of great help and the object to be serialized can have other reference types as members that may inherit from other base class, so serializer may need known types

**Formatted XML:**

```
<ArrayOfStock xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Stock>
    <ProductCode>12345</ProductCode>
    <ProductPrice>10.32</ProductPrice>
  </Stock>
  <Stock>
    <ProductCode>45632</ProductCode>
    <ProductPrice>5.43</ProductPrice>
  </Stock>
</ArrayOfStock>
```

**Without Formatting:**

```
<ArrayOfStock xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><Stock><ProductCode>123456</ProductCode><ProductPrice>10.57</ProductPrice></Stock><Stock><ProductCode>789123</ProductCode><ProductPrice>133.22</ProductPrice></Stock></ArrayOfStock>
```

Code Tried:

```
Type[] _knownExpressions = new Type[]
{
     typeof(SimpleExpression),
     typeof(CompositeExpression)
};
string expression = string.Empty;
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
DataContractSerializer dcs = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(Expression), _knownExpressions);                                        
using (XmlTextWriter xmlTextWriter = new XmlTextWriter(ms, System.Text.Encoding.Default))
{
      xmlTextWriter.Formatting = Formatting.None;
      dcs.WriteObject(xmlTextWriter, expression);
      xmlTextWriter.Flush();
      xmlTextWriter.BaseStream.Position = 0;
      StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(xmlTextWriter.BaseStream);
      expression = sr.ReadToEnd();
      sr.Close();
 }
```

Comment: Please could you show the code you're already using? A [mcve] would be ideal.

Comment: What about reading line by line and add to StringBuilder and later on use it to save in csv ?

Answer (score 0):

Don't mind, I wasn't passing the right object to the serializer, the following works

```
Type[] _knownExpressions = new Type[]
{
     typeof(SimpleExpression),
     typeof(CompositeExpression)
};
string expression = string.Empty;
Expression exp = new Expression(){
   // Fill the object
};
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
DataContractSerializer dcs = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(Expression), _knownExpressions);                                        
using (XmlTextWriter xmlTextWriter = new XmlTextWriter(ms, System.Text.Encoding.Default))
{
      xmlTextWriter.Formatting = Formatting.None;
      dcs.WriteObject(xmlTextWriter, exp);
      xmlTextWriter.Flush();
      xmlTextWriter.BaseStream.Position = 0;
      StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(xmlTextWriter.BaseStream);
      expression = sr.ReadToEnd();
      sr.Close();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Xml Writer defaults to Ident = false.  So following will work :

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication137
{
    class Program
    {
        const string INPUT_FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        const string OUTPUT_FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test1.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(INPUT_FILENAME);
            XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(OUTPUT_FILENAME);
            doc.WriteTo(writer);
            writer.Flush();
            writer.Close();
        }

    }
}
```